# Processes of a single threaded program

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, process

If a program is written in a single threaded language, does that mean that when it is executed only a single process exists for it at a time (no concurrent processes)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process is just a separate memory space. A thread is just a unit of execution on a process. A process can have multiple threads. A thread cannot coexist between multiple processes.

Answer (score 1):

When you run a single-threaded program (assuming the language runtime does not introduce any other threads) there exists only one thread in the process. That doesn't mean that there exists only one process for that program because multiple instances of the same program might be running.